# Can I add Google Maps as WMS layer to GeoMedia?

Tags: geoserver, wms, google, geomedia

My primary target is to make a WMS layer for Google Maps and load it to GeoMedia professional.

I read a lot for the past few months and I can't do it only with reading, so I decided to install GeoServer and give it a try. It didn't work so far.

I'm loading a shapefile which I generated from GeoMedia, but I can't figure how to add a map (Google Maps) to my WMS.

It will be nice if someone can help me with some information or example how to do it (if it is possible). I'm 90% sure that it is possible, but I don't know how to do it.

First I created a shapefile from GeoMedia. After that I loaded the same shapefile to GeoServer, I added some styles and I created my WMS.  After that I loaded the WMS to GeoMedia.

The problem is that I want to have a Google Maps or Bing maps as a background for my WMS.

I created an HTML file of Google Maps and added my WMS on it, I put it in my geoserver/www dir and started it from my browser as "localhost:8080/geoserver/www/myfilename.html" and its working fine.

[image]

The problem is when I tried to add the same file to GeoMedia - there is an error. I clicked on more to see the problem and I get this:

> Version negotiation failed. The WMS does not support the versions
>   supported by the data server (1.3.0/1.1.1/1.1.0/1.0.0).

I made a screenshot of the error message:

[image].

Can someone tell me why I receive this error?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: why is my question put on hold?

Comment: For the reasons in my comment and the On Hold notice. It remained on hold but you had not replied to my comment to let me know that you had added more details. Three users had noticed and voted to re-open but it still needed two ordinary user votes or one moderator vote (which I just supplied) to re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that by localhost:8080/geoserver/www/myfilename.html you just open html file on the server, it is not valid wms address. For example http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities is a valid wms address and GetCapabilities request returns xml file. 
As far as I know google maps does not proide wms service and google maps api license agreement does not allow you to use its data outside of its api.

Comment: I know which is my real WMS adress , but the question is how to put a map on it as a background it dosn't mater which map. I just need to find out how to insert a map to my WMS layer.

Comment: You cannot insert  map to wms layer, you can add wms layer and another layer(the map you want to add) to the project as separate layers in the tool you use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ,but can you tell me how to create map layer and where to load it ( Geoserver or Geomedia). I tried to find a map layer , but with no result so far. If you have a map layer could you send it to me or post a way to create it.

Comment: Probably pdf at http://community.hexagongeospatial.com/hmrkh95973/attachments/hmrkh95973/eTGeoMedia/25/1/Consuming%20A%20WMS%20Service%20In%20GeoMedia%20script.pdf may help.

Comment: There is just an tutorial how to load a wms. I saw that they import the blue marble map with this wms and that mean there is an option to load a map with wms connection . But again here is the main question how to do it? If someona has any idea please let me know.